# How do i fix weekofyear('20121231') return 1?

Tags: mysql

`weekofyear('20121231')` returns 1 whereas `weekofyear('20121230')` returns 52

```
Mysql Ver 5,1,47 Cummunity Nt / Windows 7 32 Bit / ODBC 5.1.10 /
First day of Week : Sunday
```

It should return 53 but its returning 1,
`week('20121231',1)`, `week('20121230')` return 53 in both the cases

Comment: WEEKOFYEAR() is a compatibility function that is equivalent to
WEEK(date,3)

Answer (score 3):

[`week`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) takes a lot of arguments, [`weekofyear`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) is just one of those forms, it's the same as `week([date], 3)`.

Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to see the different alternatives.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5411)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear), `weekofyear('20121231')` is *not* equivalent to `week('20121231',1)`:

> `WEEKOFYEAR()` is a compatibility function that is equivalent to
>   `WEEK(date,3)`.

Testing it:

```
mysql> SELECT weekofyear('20121231'), week('20121231',1), week('20121231',3);
+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| weekofyear('20121231') | week('20121231',1) | week('20121231',3) |
+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                      1 |                 53 |                  1 |
+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```